# ASP.NET 5 Class Libraries (Package) and target frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, class-library, .net-framework-version

In the simple case that I create a new Solution and then add a new ASP.NET 5 web app and a Class Library (Package) to the solution.

**There are the default framework references for each project:**
Web App: dnxcore50 and dnx451
Class Library (Package): net451, dotnet5.4

If I try to add a reference from the web app to the class library there are issues. It adds successfully, but from the web app when I go to create a new instance of a class from the library it can't find anything. I believe this is because the class library must support the frameworks in the project.

Do I really need to add all 4 frameworks to my class library?

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { },
    "dnx451": { },
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
```

Shouldn't I be able to only use dnxcore50 and dnx451 in the class library and still use the System namespace? As soon as I remove net451 and dotnet5.4 I get a bunch of errors in regards to the System namespace.

Comment: It would really help if you'd provide a complete example including at least *some* sample error messages rather than "a bunch of errors". Note that these aren't really "framework references" so much as "framework targets".

Comment: for now I've been changing my class libraries to match the web app, that is change dotnet5.4 to dnxcore50. net451 seems to work ok so I leave that as it is. you don't want to add all 4 because dnx451 is the same thing as net451 aka the desktop framework and dotnet5.4 is the same thing as dnxcore50 aka coreclr

Comment: @JonSkeet I apologize, by errors I mean that my webapp can't see the class library. Meaning I can't add a using statement to the class library.

Comment: @JoeAudette It seems like the only working solution is to change dotnet5.4 to dnxcore50 and leave net451 as is. As soon as I remove net451 and replace it with dnx451 I can't access the System namespace which makes absolutely no sense since dnx451 works completely fine in the web app and I can access the System namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class library, remove dnxcore50 and dnx451

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": { },
  "dotnet5.4": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. There is documentation out there saying that the class library must have the same framework targets as the asp.net 5 web app in order for the asp.net 5 web app to be able to reference it. Meaning if my webapp has dnxcore50 and dnx451 pointers then I must add them to the class library. I am just wondering why the class library won't work when only dnxcore50 and dnx451 (by wont work I mean the web app can't find it) are the target frameworks. I lost access to the System namespace.

Comment: Actually you are correct, the class library (package) works out of the box without needing to change any of the framework targets. I guess there was something wrong with my intellisense or my laptop was just behind after adding the reference so it made me start looking into changing the frameworks. On my desktop everything works 100% fine when adding a new asp.net 5 project and then a class library (Package). Referencing the class library from the project.